# Windows Form Control

Tags: windows, forms

I would like to create my own control for a Windows application using Visual Studio.NET 2010.

The control will look like a text box but will have 4 additional properties out of which 3 will take integer type values and one of type Enum. 
Please note that none of these properties will affect the appearance of the the control. 
I would like to use the same User Interface as it is for a text box.

Can you help me how to start about this?

Thanks in advance
 Nishant

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that inherits `TextBox` and add whatever properties you like.

Comment: would this be a user control or custom control? I would like this to appear as a part of the Tool box too. Thanks

Comment: Any class that inherits `Control` (even indirectly) will automatically appear in the Toolbox.  User controls and custom controls are just classes that inherit `UserControl` or `Control`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user control class which inherits from **System.Windows.Forms.UserControl**. You can see an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx)